# Firebase storage rules for writing at specific path not considered

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I have a very simple Firebase Storage structure:

```
> check-in-station-content
> reports
```

These are two folders and I am trying to set up a restriction on the **check-in-station-content** to accept only video/mp4 files, not bigger than 30MB and to be uploaded only by authenticated parties. So, my rules looks like this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
    }

    match /check-in-station-content {
      // Allow write files, subject to the constraints:
      // 1) File is less than 30MB
      // 2) Content type is video/mp4
      match /{videoId} {
        allow write: if request.auth != null && request.resource.size < 30 * 1024 * 1024 && request.resource.contentType.matches('video/mp4')
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then, when I go to the UI for the storage and click the **Upload** button, nothing is stopping me of uploading whatever file having whatever size

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the Firebase console, you actually bypass all the security rules, since you are interacting with Cloud Firestore as the owner of the project (or another role with similar access, e.g. Editor). The rules apply only when you are using one of the Client SDKs or the other Client APIs.

By the way, note that your rule matches the `check-in-station-background-content` path and no the `check-in-station-content` one.

Comment: Yes, you're right I mistyped the match path. I just edited it.

Comment: @user2128702 The other part of Renaud's answer is also correct: when you upload a file (or perform any other operation) in the Firebase console, it bypasses the security rules. To test the security rules in the console, you'll want to use the Rules Playground that is showing in the bottom left of the rules editor.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for the precision/clarification mentioning the Rules Playground, Frank.